# Python package to parse identifiers in a program (C, Scala, Lisp)?

Tags: python, c, parsing, scala, lisp

In the title I mention 3 different languages in which I would like to find out if a python package exists which can give me a list of identifiers for a program in any of those; so doesn't have to be all three of them as I doubt it there would be one like that. So my question is does a function or class exist in python that allows me too get a list of identifiers for a specific program in a language, preferably one in the 3 I listed in the title. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Could you give more context?  It seems like you want to write a Python program to parse a C, Scala, or Lisp program and output a list of identifiers, but that isn't 100% clear from this question.

Comment: I didn't see a point in repeating the title in the body, but I apologize for the ambiguity. I was more hoping one existed to do that in python, if not then I would like to know that.

Comment: You're looking for a Python package. See my edit.

Comment: Do you simply want to extract tokens from a file? By any chance, do you want to **identify** the language a file is written in?

Comment: No, I do not want to identify the language. I do however want to extract the function names, class names, type identifiers like String, etc. This is what I mean by identifiers.

Comment: In C Python, or can you use Jython?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, this is not possible without having a nearly complete language implementation.

There is a rudimentary preprocessor in C, which could allow to mask function declarations from an ad hoc scanning. There is a powerful metaprogramming in Lisp, which means you can only extract the definitions using a full-featured Lisp compiler, simple parsing won't help at all.

Scala is the simplest of these three, but still its syntax is over-bloated and you'll need at least a complete parser. Python is not nearly a right tool for doing this sort of things any way.

Answer (score 1):

There's [pycparser](http://code.google.com/p/pycparser/), which you can use to generate a C AST from code and then traverse it to get whatever you want.

There's [this simple lisp interpreter](http://norvig.com/lispy.html) in Python from which you should be able to scrap the parser.

And I doubt there's anything similar and readily available for Scala, but you can use something like [ply](http://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=ply&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDMQFjAA&url=http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/&ei=mJieT7aqE5Ki8QS7yq2nDw&usg=AFQjCNHv-eylAV812hDOEVG2GLTa0AOZyA) to make a parser. It won't be as easy, but will do.

Comment: Yea, I was looking at Ply, but its kind of daunting to go through its tutorial. But thanks for the input.

Comment: You'll probably have an easier time by going through the examples than the tutorial.